# How to add dot at the end of the numbers

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

Hello I wanna add dot at the end of the numbers like: 17.54, but I have some problems with it:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win['bg'] = '#1a1a1a'
win.title('Calculator')
win.resizable(False, False)


monitor = Entry(win, width=22, borderwidth=7,
                highlightthickness=0, bd=6, font=("Arial", 28, 'bold'),)
monitor.place(x=11, y=30)
monitor.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6)


def buttondot():
    get_number = monitor.get()
    global action
    global saved_number
    saved_number = int(get_number)
    monitor.delete(0, END)
    action = "dot"
    if action == 'dot':
        monitor.insert(float(saved_number, '.'))
        monitor.delete(0, END)

buttondot = Button(win, text=".", bg='#804d00', padx=40, pady=20, command=buttondot).grid(
    row=5, column=1, stick='wens')
```

when i click on the dot i have this problem: TypeError: float expected at most 1 argument, got 2

Comment: Why are you running the command `knopkadot` when your function is `buttondot`??

Comment: I made a mistake, now I fixed it and tried it anyway, it didn’t help

Comment: Ask yourself again what do you want from `float(saved_number, '.')`? Also why do you delete everything just after inserting something into `monitor`?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling float() you are giving it more arguments than it can handle.

```
float(saved_number, '.')
```

should only be `float(saved_number)`